# Parameterized archunit test?

Tags: java, junit, archunit

I have a list of method names for which I'd like to write a ArchUnit test in the form of:

```
ArchRule rule = methods().that().haveName("methodName").should(new ArchCondition<JavaMethod>.   ("test") {
    @Override
    public void check(JavaMethod javaMethod, ConditionEvents conditionEvents) {
      ...
    }
  });

  rule.check(classesToTest);
}
```

}

I tried to use @ParameterizedTest and @ArchUnit in combination, but this didn't work. I also tried creating the ArchRule in a for loop, but this fails when the first violations happens and doesn't check the rules I'm trying to test later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found the solution myself. What you can do in the following case is to create a list of ArchUnit rules:

```
List<ArchRule> rules = new ArrayList();

for (....) {
   rules.add(...)
}
```

And then, you can combine them all together and test:

```
CompositeArchRule.of(rules).check(classesToTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

`@ArchTest`s are evaluated by ArchUnit's own test runner, which does not support JUnit's `@ParameterizedTest`s.

Maybe you can create your `ArchRule` with a parameterized method that allows you to create

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule rule1 = createRule(1);

@ArchTest
ArchRule rule2 = createRule(2);

@ArchTest
ArchRule rule3 = createRule(3);

// ...
```

with just a little overhead?

Alternatively, you can also write ArchUnit tests as plain JUnit tests if you take care of the class file import yourself, cf. https://www.archunit.org/getting-started.